# C++ vector pointers

Tags: c++

as this is my first attempt at using pointers for vectors, I did some research on it and tried it on my program but however it doesn't give me the results I wanted,though it's closed to it.Please forgive me if I asking a lousy question.

Comment: You need to shorten this down if possible. It's pretty long and most people wont be bothered to read it/answer it

Comment: @PreetKukreti most are usually confused if i shorten my codes

Comment: It would help you to try to narrow it down to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and others as well. This is the kind of problem you can easily track down by stepping through the program in a debugger.

Comment: You list two MissionPlan.cpp files but one second looks like a header file. You should correct that as well. Doing more troubleshooting would help narrow down what is causing this and would help you determine code to include

Answer (score 3):

Your error is when you print the contents of the vector, not when you add data to it.

```
for (int i= 0; i<5; i++) {
    if(storeData.empty()) {
        cout <<"<no other records available>" << endl;
    }
    // error: storeData[i] may not be valid
    else if(storeData[i].getCivIndex() == 0 && storeData[i].getXOrdinate() == 0 && storeData[i].getYOrdinate() == 0) {
        cout << "<no other records available>" << endl;
    }
    else { 

        cout << "Civ Index:"<< storeData[i].getCivIndex() << ",at Sector("<< storeData[i].getXOrdinate() << "," << storeData[i].getYOrdinate() <<")" << endl;

    }
}
```

You're always looking to read 5 records here even if the vector contains fewer. You should check the size of the vector before dereferencing it, otherwise you are reading random memory and undefined behavior will result.

```
    if(storeData.size() <= i) {
        cout <<"<no other records available>" << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(storeData.size() > 5) {
    storeData.resize(5);
}
```

first I think here you mean `if(storeData.size()<5)` otherwise the following printing will certainly fail since you only have access to `storeData[0]` while you try to access others.

When you do `resize` without a second argument, the items added into the vector will be default constructed. In case the `PointTwoD` struct doesn't provide a default constructor, its data members won't be initialized, which means it could end up with random values. That's why you have those weird numbers. (0 is also possible).

The solution is to define a default constructor for `pointTwoD` and set its data member to 0 in the initialization list or [call `resize` with a second argument.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)

Comment: manage to solve it already. thanks for your advice